# Cucumber and scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd

I'm just learning Cucumber and BDD way to create applications. 
When I'm start learning rails by http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ I'm use scaffolding to generate CRUD functionality and skeleton to my controllers and views. This way give me large speed up versus PHP custom writing code. But when I'm looking to cucumber screencasts, reading comments about BDD, or looking to https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora source code - all of them doesn't use scaffold. When I try to write tests I'm spent long time to compose and test, but I know that the basic code which generated by scaffold isn't crashable. That is my question: How give compromise between BDD and scaffold speed?

Comment: Just relax:) You'll forget about scaffolds very soon if you'll continue actively exploring rails world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scaffold serves as a good starting point whilst you are getting to know the TDD/BDD cycle.  I found that when I first read the [RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) that it was confusing with what to use when and why !  Then along came the [Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) which helps a little more since it takes you through the steps a little slower (although the book is still in beta, but a fantastic resource).

One other great resource that helped was a blog post by Sarah Mei called "[Outside-in BDD: How?](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2010/05/29/outside-in-bdd/)".  What is nice about this post is the discussion of the flow and style that you use as a developer.  This was useful since it puts some context around the style of doing BDD and not just a re-hash of a basic example.

Of course there is the usual debate that 'real programmers' shouldn't use the scaffold.  That may be true for a large scale, production application.  The reality is that we all have to learn and start somewhere and Rails is no exception; it's a large framework and once you add in RSpec + Cucumber the breadth and depth grows very fast.